# Unhandled Exception when executing via RDP (OK when local)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7-x64, rdp

I have recently put together a new development machine and loaded Windows 7 64 bit and VS2010.

I copied over all my projects (VB) from the old machine which was Windows 7 x86 and VS2008.

After following the conversion wizard in VS2010 and installing a third-party component I had forgotten about, my solutions opened and executed fine on the new machine.

Then I tried to work on one of my projects via RDP from a Windows XP machine (something I have done many, many times with the old machine) and the project crashes when run.  I get the "no source availiable" tab and an AccessViolationException as soon as the splash screen has loaded.  Going back to local operation, the project runs fine.

I've Googled this one to death and I can't find anything that relates to this problem at all.  Any sugggestions would be gratefully received.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the message and stack trace?

Comment: When I run the project, the splash screen appears, then the IDE appears to freeze.  I close vshost from the task bar icon.  I then get the dialog "vshost-clr2 is not responding".  I close that and I get the unhandled exception dialog "AcessViolationException was unhandled.  Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.".  The only thing I can do then is OK the dialog, which takes me out of debug mode so I don't think I can then see the stack trace.

Comment: Try attaching a second copy of VS to the first one and using its debugger.

Comment: Any idea where I could find some directions on how to do that?  I've uninstalled VS2010 and installed VS2008 and get exactly the same problem.  Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Open a second copy, click Tools, Attach to Process, then select the first `devenv.exe`.

Comment: Do you have any system extensions (eg, multi-monitor stuff) that may be doing funny things with windows?

Answer (score 0):

I do have multiple monitors but have never had a problem before with RDP. Anyways, I found other problems when opening other, older, projects in VS2010 so I uninstalled and reverted to VS2008. All OK now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue running Visual Studio 2010 via RDP where the IDE contents except the Solution Explorer wouldn't render. I went to Options->Environment->General->Visual experience and turned off the the "rich client visual experience" options. I suspect turning off "Use hardware graphics acceleration if available" did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had also problem with RDP working in "windows 10"
My connection other computers always run successful, but closing after 5-15 second. I very long try fix this error. And I open this exception in VS2015 and read full excaption:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFBE35A8283 (ntdll.dll) in mstsc.exe: 0xC0000374: Куча была повреждена (parameters: 0x00007FFBE35FF6B0).
```

At first I thinked my PC have truble with RAM memory, but I decide change RDP settings and it began work without problem.
I changed the picture quality and uncheck using printer in other window.
My rdp workin very nice now.
I tried many fixes
From the microsoftware, with updates and system files, but nothing helped. I am writing now if someone with the same collision can solve temporarily the problem by lowering the quality of the picture. On a remote computer, it may be very important to simply connect, especially if it is a server.
[image]
[image]